# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR with Code: 0xC020901E

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package that runs perfectly fine on Visual Studio 2013 but when I deploy the package to SQL server agent and execute it there I get the following error:

```
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Lookup" failed because error code 0xC020901E occurred, and the error row disposition on "Lookup.Outputs[Lookup Match Output]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
```

The package is running on Sql Server 2014.

Comment: The error is telling you there was a lookup error. I *assume* you've configured those rows that fail to go elsewhere, so look at those rows. There will also be more logs into the SSISDB logs that likely give you more verbose information. We can't help you with this error though, as it literally tells you the problem and we don't have access to your instance.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. I was able to solve this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed how to handle the rows with no matching entries to Redirect rows to no match output.The default was set to fail component.